# Combat Excel Formula Injection during DataPresenterExcelExporter.Export

Tags: excel, export-to-excel, infragistics

I am using DataPresenterExcelExporter by Infragistics.Windows.DataPresenter; to export data to an Excel file
However, I would like to prevent Formula Injection during the process meaning I would like to remove formulas in the newly created Excel file
Is there a property or ExportOptions I can take advantage of to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

I don’t recall the wpf exporter automatically exporting formulas. Are you sure you are not creating formulas in code? Or perhaps you are using the windows forms UltraGridExcelExport in which case there is an ExportFormulas property you can set to false.